# What closeness measures are appropriate to this undirected graph?

Tags: geometry, pgrouting, routing, graph, spatial-relationship

I need a way to measure the **closeness centrality** of every single NODE(i) in respect to all NODES(j),

**1 NODE(i) to all NODES(j)**

and, another measure that describe somehow the geometric properties of the network created by NODES(j) with themselves.

**all NODES(j) to all NODES(j)**

I know this is part of Graph Theory, but it is also a routing matter and I am sure spatial gurus can understand this network.

[image: nodes network]

Comment: They identical, unless it is weighted graph.

Comment: @FelixIP: Let me rephtrase the question. Every node(i), the brown ones, will have a closeness parameter as calculated by the sum of distances of all connecting lines (edges) to the nodes (j), the blue ones. In fact, there are 3 edges that connect every brown node to one blue node, as we have 3 blue nodes (kind of hubs). But what would be an appropriate  geometric descriptor of the polygon created by connecting all nodes (j), the blue ones?? Cheers

Comment: You might call it eulerian circuit, see networkx documentation. Not sure how it is related to a title of your post.